# Verify certificate is valid for encryption/decryption

Tags: c#, certificate, rsa, x509, rsacryptoserviceprovider

As mentioned in questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391342/bad-key-exception-when-decrypting-with-rsacryptoserviceprovider-c-net), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037072/bad-key-exception-for-certificates-with-exportable-private-key) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12872657/bad-key-cryptographicexception-when-trying-to-decrypt), if you try to encrypt/decrypt using a certificate that's only valid for digital signatures, you'll get a CryptographicException: "Bad Key" from RSACryptoServiceProvider.

My question is how verify up front (e.g. as you're configuring certificates in your application), whether a certificate is valid for this purpose. I found that an approach like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32704248/how-do-i-verify-certificate-for-keyusage) using only the v3 extensions is *not* sufficient, as RSACryptoServiceProvider works just fine for decrypt using a cert with v3 extension of only DigitalSignatures.

So I assume that I'll need to check for specific list of OIDs using code similar to what I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14705157/how-to-check-if-a-x509-certificate-has-extended-validation-switched-on):

```
private static bool IsCertificateOkForDecryption(X509Certificate2 certificate)
{
    string[] validOids = 
    {
        //TODO: what goes here??
    };

    return (
            certificate.Extensions.Where(e=> validOids.Contains(e.Oid.Value)
            .Any()
        );
}
```

(code is not exact -- just for illustration)

Is there an easier way?

If not, where can I find the list of OIDs which are valid?

For background, see also the [Kentor.AuthServices SAML issue](https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices/issues/412) that sparked this question.